# Why is /boot/config.txt executable?

Tags: pi-3, boot, security, permissions, pi-b

- FYI, I installed the R-PI minimal image with `dd` myself onto an sd card

I was messing with the boot config when I realized that this file was set as executable. Looking at the config, I don't see why it would need the execute permissions. Additionally according to the [short documentation page here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/), there is no mention of having to set the execute bit on creating your own `config.txt` file. Also the docs just say that the config is read on boot, not executed. Lastly, the execution bit is set on all users which seems like a mistake, as the file is only ever utilized by root during the boot process

Can I remove the execute permissions? Or is there a reason that it is default set to execute?

Comment: It's on a FAT partition so the executable bit is completely ignored. The /boot partition is mounted with NOEXEC anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files in the `/boot` directory are from the first partition of the SD card that's been mounted there during the boot process. Because the first partition is formatted as a [FAT filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system) the files don't have the same meta-data available as when using, for example, the ext4 filesystem.

The [mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) command used to mount the partition has to somehow map the meta-data expected by the underlying filesystem from the mounted filesystem and this ends up with some of the flags being meaningless or mapped to different meanings. In your example, the [File Allocation Tables](http://www.tavi.co.uk/phobos/fat.html) on the SD card has no concept of a file being "executable" (I believe that actual vFAT systems look at the file extension to figure out if it's executable or not: it's a function of the OS, not the filesystem) so *all* the files will have the executable bit set when mounted.

There are other features missing in "vFAT" that can lead to odd behaviour when being mounted, such as no UID/GID; coarser timestamps that start at a different Epoch and restricted filenames for example. You can adjust how some of these are "handled", look at some of the options listed under the "*Mount options for fat*" section in the `man 8 mount` pages.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Operating_system_variations